# Group by subquery on the same table in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to use CakePHP3's Query Builder for the following query, but did not succeed so far... My main problem is that I don't know how should I alias the outer query to access in the subquery.

For the full story, I have the following table:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| from | to   | type | dtime            | price_1 | price_2 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| AAAA | BBBB | T1   | 2017.01.01 11:00 | 200     |     300 |
| AAAA | BBBB | T2   | 2017.01.01 18:00 | 250     |     350 |
| CCCC | BBBB | T1   | 2017.01.01 12:00 | 100     |     200 |
| CCCC | BBBB | T2   | 2017.01.01 16:00 | 150     |     250 |
| AAAA | BBBB | T1   | 2017.01.02 10:00 | 2000    |    3500 |
| AAAA | BBBB | T2   | 2017.01.02 19:00 | 1900    |    3000 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I expect to receive the following:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| from | to   | type | dtime            | least(price_1,price_2) |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| AAAA | BBBB | T1   | 2017.01.01 11:00 | 200                    |
| CCCC | BBBB | T1   | 2017.01.01 12:00 | 100                    |
| AAAA | BBBB | T2   | 2017.01.02 19:00 | 1900                   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So basically I'm collecting the cheapest routes for each given day (keeping in mind that there can be more different times for a route per day).

So far I've succeeded to create the following query which works properly:

```
SELECT from, to, type, CAST(dtime AS DATE) AS stdd
FROM routes AS r1
WHERE LEAST(price_1, price_2) IN (
    SELECT MIN(price_1, price_2)
    FROM routes
    WHERE from = r1.from
      AND to = r1.to
      AND CAST(dtime AS DATE) = CAST(r1.dtime AS DATE)
    GROUP BY CAST(dtime AS DATE), from, to
)
GROUP BY stdd, from, to;
```

And the problem comes now... I could not create a proper CakePHP3 Query. Could someone help me?

Thank in advance,
Zoltan

Update 1: Added current CakePHP3 code snippet:

The original code:

```
return $this
    ->find()
    ->select(['dtime', 'type', 'from', 'to', 'price_1', 'price_2', 'stdd' => 'cast(dtime as DATE)'])
    ->order(['dtime' => 'ASC', 'from' => 'ASC', 'to' => 'ASC'])
    ->group(['dtime','from','to']);
```

I wanted to enhance this somehow (the code I've tried has already been deleted, so I try to reproduce it here):

```
$subQuery = $this
    ->find()
    ->select(['min(least(price_1, price_2))'])
    ->where(['from' => ???outer.from???,
             'to' => ???outer.to???,
             'cast(dtime as DATE)' => 'cast(???outer.dtime??? as DATE)'])
    ->group(['cast(dtime as DATE)', from, to]);
return $this
    ->find()
    ->select(['dtime', 'type', 'from', 'to', 'price_1', 'price_2', 'stdd' => 'cast(dtime as DATE)'])
    ->where(['least(price_1, price_2)' => $subQuery])
    ->order(['dtime' => 'ASC', 'from' => 'ASC', 'to' => 'ASC'])
    ->group(['dtime','from','to']);
```

Update 2: More concrete code snippet:

```
 $text = "(1000,3000,5000)"; //select should return something like this
 $subQuery = $this
      ->find()
      ->select(['X' => 'min(least(price_1, coalesce(price_1, price_2), '
                . 'coalesce(price_1, price_3), coalesce(price_1, price_4), '
                . 'coalesce(price_1, price_5), coalesce(price_1, price_6)))'])
      ->where(['from' => ???outer.from???,
               'to' => ???outer.to???,
               'cast(dtime as DATE) = cast(???outer.dtime??? as DATE)'])
      ->group(['cast(dtime as DATE)', 'from', 'to']);
  return $this
      ->find()
      ->select(['dtime', 'from', 'to', 'type', 'price_1', 'price_2', 'price_3', 'price_4', 'price_5', 'price_6',
                'stdd' => 'cast(dtme as DATE)'])
      ->where(['least(price_1, coalesce(price_1, price_2), '
                . 'coalesce(price_1, price_3), coalesce(price_1, price_4), '
                . 'coalesce(price_1, price_5), coalesce(price_1, price_6)) in ' . $text])
                //=> $ar])
                //. ' in (37090,111)'])
                //=> $ar])//$subQuery->toArray()])
      ->order(['dtime' => 'ASC', 'from' => 'ASC', 'to' => 'ASC'])
      ->group(['stdd','from','to']);
```

I've created the both the query and subquery. If I replace the ???variable??? placeholders then they return the correct value. But then the concrete question: how can I alias the outer "main" query to access its fields in the subquery?

Comment: What have you got for your CakePHP3 Query so far?

Comment: Hi wogsland, I've updated my question with the code snippets. Thanks.

Comment: There's quite a few things wrong in your example, but this question is limited to aliasing, right?

Comment: I've updated the description with the current code I have. The only open question is then basically that how can I alias the outer "main" query to access its fields in the subquery (in the placeholders).